# How to Fetch the new event log from the previous event id

Tags: powershell, event-log

I have a script which is fetching the event logs from multiple remote servers for the first time.For the second time it should check it is not the same eventID which i first fetch for every remote server or it should be greater from the previous eventID. SO every time it should not fetch the same event log.

How can i achieve this. Any Suggestions would be helpful

The Script:

```
#Give your local path on where you are saving server.txt file
$ComputerList = "E:\Event\servers.txt"

#Script Vaiables

$Computers = Get-Content $ComputerList | Where-Object { $_ }
$WindowslogName = "Application"
$WindowsMessageMatch = "Event 'Task Stopped'"
$TodaysDate = Get-Date
$TodaysDate.ToUniversalTime()

$AfterDate=Get-Date
$AfterDate.AddDays(-1)
$AfterDate.ToUniversalTime()

#Query Event Log
foreach($Computer in $Computers)
{
       Write-Host "Fetching Event Logs $Computer"
       $Event=Get-Eventlog -After $AfterDate  -Before $TodaysDate -LogName Application -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -InstanceId 602 -Message "*Event 'Task Stopped'*" -Newest 1 -ComputerName $Computer
       $Event|Format-List * 
}
```

Comment: This question is quite confusing. You use "instance id", "eventID" and "event log ID" interchangeably, but you seem to be interested in the entry index?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen My Qeuestion is for the second time it should not fetch the previous eventlog with the same eventID

Comment: @Vishal I think what has us confused is that there is only one Application event log and you will only ever get the newest event with ID 602 based on your code.  Do you mean that you only want to get the event if it is newer than the last event you captured?

Comment: @MikeGaruccio Yes, i want to capture the newest event because i may need to run this script every 5 min if there is no new entry it will capture already captured event.

Comment: The newest event with ID 602 is what your current code would get you.  Do you need a specific behavior if the newest event is the same event as the last time the script ran? Or is there some other problem?

Comment: @MikeGaruccio I need a specific behaviour for the newest event is the same event as last time script ran

Comment: And what would that behavior be?

Comment: @MikeGaruccio If that eventlog has same EventRecordID it should not fetch that ID ,if it is different it should fetch the eventlog

Comment: I think we're getting lost in terms again. Do you mean it needs to fetch that event only if it's new, or that if the event is new the entire log needs to be fetched

Comment: @MikeGaruccio If event is new i need to fetch the entire logs